# Aggregate pipeline with $match not working in php mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to aggregate a field with matching value.

So far I have following Query

```
array(
'aggregate' => wines,
'pipeline'=>
    array(                              
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => array('name' => '$name', "winery" => $winery )
            )                                   
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => $_id.winery,
                'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
            )
        )

    ),
    '$match' => array('wine_type'=>'red wine')
);
```

The above query gives aggregated wines but it does not filters Red wine.

Note: I run this in command function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very clear in your question, but you appear to have $match in the wrong place:

```
array(
    'aggregate' => wines,
    'pipeline'=>
        array(                              
            array(
               '$match' => array('wine_type'=>'red wine')
            ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => array('name' => '$name', "winery" => $winery )
                 )                                  
            ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => $_id.winery,
                    count' => array('$sum' => 1)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

You should get used to the standard invocation of aggregate rather than the `runCommand` form. Future releases will return a cursor for the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It helped. The php lib which I'm using does not support aggregate function directly. Will update that :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the field doesn't exist by the end of the aggregation due to the multiple group. This is since the result of one pipeline is passed to the other, so in fact you are searching for a field of `wine_type` while there is only `_id` and `count`.

Also you have a syntax error, the `$match` is on the wrong level.

You can put the `$match` at the beginning or you can add the field to the list of projected group fields in your aggregation.